# Database unable to connect

Tags: java, database, connection, database-connection

I have a database project, Im trying to connect to database from netbeabs and I created a connection class which is ;

public class Global {

```
public static Connection createConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    System.out.println("Checking if Driver is registered with DriverManager.");
try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
        System.out.println("exit.");
        System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("make a connection.");
try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ydb_lib", "postgres", "postgres");
        System.out.println("Success.");
} catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect: exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

}

and I call this class from the methods with this;

```
      Connection c = Global.createConnection();
```

after I run the program the output is;

```
      Checking if Driver is registered with DriverManager.
      Couldn't find the driver!
      exit.
```

I cant see the problem my username, password, driver name, database name is right so what do you think could be the problem??

Comment: What is the Data base you are using .. Make sure that DB Driver JAR Files are in your lib folder ..

Comment: yes, I think thats the problem thanks @looser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem may due to the project can not find posrtgesql JDBC driver  when  running .

so add jar in the path of  class libraries.
Get a PostgreSQL JDBC driver at this URL : http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Your database driver jar is not on the classpath.

Please also print out your exceptions rather than just ignoring them and printing out your own error messages. This could save you a load of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.postgresql.Driver` class is not in your classpath.